Loki query for show duplicate session nginx
Hi all i've shipping nginx access log (in json) to loki and wanted to visualize duplicated session established every 1 Second for period of 1 Hour.
count by (address,uri) (count_over_time({filename="/var/log/nginxaccess.log"} | json [1s])) >1

But this query Only show duplicate session for 1 Seconond ago.
wait for yours help, thanks.!
